# Create array of lists and access their values

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I have a list of Series for signals that are being imported from a file. I want to have all X values of each datapoint of every Series in one seperate list and be able to access them via a loop.
I was thinking of creating an array of Lists.

Here is what I have tried so far.

```
List<double>[] datapointsX = new List<double>[Signals.Count];
int i=0;
foreach(var signal in Signals){
 datapointsX[i] = new List<double>();
 for(int j=0; j<signal.Points.Count; j++){
datapointsX[i].Add(signal.Points[j].XValue);
}
Console.Writeline(datapointsX[0][1]);
i++;
}
```

But I get an exception that the object is not set to an instance or an object. The error is at the Console.Writeline function.

Comment: any specific reason for not using simply a `List<List<double>>` ?

Comment: In the first line you create an array to hold multiple lists. But you didn't create an instance of list (there is no `new List()` in your code) before trying to call `Add` method.

Comment: Between the `foreach` and the `for` add: `datapointsX[i] = new List<double>();` Array contents are initialised to null, so the elements at `datapointsX[i]` will all be null unless you explicitly initialise the elements.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I edit it to be more clear